# How to execute functions of other components that take too long to execute in a way that doesn't block UI

Tags: multithreading, qt, qml

From the `main.qml` i want to call functions from other components and get their results in a way that doesn't block the UI thread.

After i have the results of these functions I want to push them into a "common" array.

How can I do it with QML? What would be a possible solution?

I'm going to illustrate in code what I want to do (I'm aware this would never work) :

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import AsyncWorker 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    Page {
        id: page
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            margins: 10
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 10
            RowLayout {
                WorkerScript
                {
                    id: importScanWorkerScript
                    source: "script.js"
                    onMessage: {
                        console.log(messageObject.data1)
                        console.log(messageObject.data2)
                        spinner.running = false;
                    }
                }



                BusyIndicator {
                    id: spinner
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    running: false
                }

                Panel1 {
                    id: panel1
                }
                Panel2 {
                    id: panel2
                }

                Button {
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                    text: qsTr("Run asynchronous")
                    onClicked: {
                        spinner.running = true
                        //Is there a way to run the functions of the 2 panels in a workerscript??
                        importScanWorkerScript.sendMessage(panel1,panel2)
                    }
                }
            }
            Item {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Panel1.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Item {
    function info() {
        var j=0
        for(var i=0; i<99999999; i++) {
            j+=i
        }
        return j
    }
}
```

`Panel2.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Item {
    function info() {
        var j=0
        for(var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
            j+=i
        }
        return j
    }
}
```

`script.js`

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(obj1,obj2) {
    var obj1Test = obj1.info()//not working
    var obj2Test = obj2.info()//not working
    WorkerScript.sendMessage({ 'data1': obj1Test, "data2" : obj2Test })
}
```

Comment: I guess that [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html) already provides nice example of passing arguments to the script.

Comment: @folibis yes i've read it. I know i can pass a jsobject. But is there a way to do something like i'm asking?

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. If you want to pass a reference to a QML item I think it is impossible due to [restriction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html#restrictions) - _script ... cannot access the properties, methods or other attributes of the QML item, nor can it access any context properties ..._

Comment: @folibis, i know that what is in my example is impossible, but i'm looking for a way to do it. I want to execute the functions of the Panels components in a separate thread and want to do something with that results.

Comment: why not make life easier and have a c++ back-end listening to signals from the `ApplicationWindow` which launches worker threads that process things in the background.

Comment: @Nmaster88 your question looks like trying to solve [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). In general there are lots of ways in Qt to handle multithreading, you need to adopt one. Try to review your design.

Comment: @troyane, I think you're right. What I'm asking is not going to work on any way. But is what I would like to be possible.

Comment: @bardao how would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an example of what I mentioned in the comments:

This example runs a timer that posts a debug message every second in a worker thread while the UI is intact.

Assume you have a class worker.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

class Worker : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
    explicit Worker(QObject* parent = nullptr): QObject(parent){
        timer.setInterval(1000);
        connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() {
            qDebug() << "executing with wait";
        });
    }
    ~Worker(){}

    Q_INVOKABLE void doSomeWork() { // modify this to accommodate your params
        //do something here
        timer.start();
    }

private:
    QTimer timer;

};
```

This is defined in main.cpp as:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "worker.h"
#include <QThread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Worker cpp;
    QThread cpp_thread;
    cpp.moveToThread(&cpp_thread);
    cpp_thread.start();
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cpp", &cpp);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

At some point in your QML you call it as:

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(obj1,obj2) {
    cpp.doSomeWork() // modify this to accommodate your params
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would get rid of the `WorkerScript` all together and directly call `cpp.doSomeWork()`

Comment: yes i think that it's better to just call it directly the assinchronous c++ function.